# SQL: Difference between "BETWEEN" vs "current_date - number"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am wondering which of the following is the best way to implement and why.

```
select * from table1 where request_time between '01/18/2012' and '02/17/2012'
```

and

```
select * from table1 where request_time > current_date - 30
```

Comment: Door #2 is preferred because it's not hard-coding the dates :D

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the dates, I use a variable for that. I work in python and use a datetime variable over there. Saying that, will the door #1 takes precedence ?

Comment: I was being overly literal and sidestepping the real issue, hence the toothy grin. I use both in different situations. I haven't seen a perceptible performance difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

I ran the two queries through some of my date tables in my database and using EXPLAIN ANALYZE I found these results:

```
explain analyze
select * from capone.dim_date where date between '01/18/2012' and '02/17/2012'
```

Total runtime: 22.716 ms

```
 explain analyze
select * from capone.dim_date where  date > current_date - 30
```

Total runtime: 65.044 ms

So it looks like the 1st option is more optimal. Of course this is biased towards my DBMS but these are still the results I got.

The table has dates ranging from 1900 to 2099 so it is rather large, and not just some dinky little table.

Answer (score 3):

Between has the inclusive ranges i.e when you issue a query like id between 2 and 10 the value of 2 and 10 will also be fetched.If you want to eliminate these values use > and <.

Also when indexes are applied say on date column > and < makes a good use of index than between.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `BETWEEN` can make the same use of indexes that relational operators can.

Comment: I do have indexing on the request_time column. The table gets 1-2 million records a day. Using the second approach, it takes forever to get the date.

Comment: may be there are different behaviors for different dbms's

Comment: Without seeing `EXPLAIN` output, it is ridiculous to make an inference about performance.

Comment: Daniel: If you are referring to my comment, sorry about that.